# how to remove task manager in rooted android device?

Tags: android, memory-management, ram

I am making an app , that should be running all the time. It should not be killed anyhow from task manager. I am willing to stop task manager so i rooted my device . Is there anyway to prevent my app from getting killed or removing the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

This may help a bit , add this in your Manifest to the respected activity , atleast it will not show the app running in recents .

```
       android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
       android:excludeFromRecents="true"
       android:noHistory="true"
```